# Using dateRangeInput to filter dataframe does not produce desired result

Tags: r, shiny

In my Shiny App, I have included a `dateRangeInput` that takes a start and end date as inputs.
I also have another `selectInput` ui element, that takes an input (excluded from this post)

An extract from **ui.R**

```
column(wellPanel(
tags$style('.input-sm {font-size: 20px; } label {font-weight: 500; margin-bottom: 30px; }'),
dateRangeInput("inp_pg1daterange", 
               label = paste('Date Range Selection'),
               start = min(results_combined$Date),
               end = max(results_combined$Date), 
               separator = " to ", 
               weekstart = 1

)

),width=3)
```

And on the **server.R** side, I expect the date inputs to:

1) Filter a dataframe
2) Convert and store the filtered dataset into a set of different variables
3) Based on a `selectInput`, display a `valueBox` with the correct value

This is what the server code looks like

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {
```

**Step 1) Filter dataframe using daterange input**

```
kpidf_pg1_totalqol= reactive({

results_combined %>%
filter(SVM_LABEL_QOL=='QoL' & Date >=input$inp_pg1daterange[[1]] & Date <=input$inp_pg1daterange[[2]])  %>%
select(`Global Segment`=globalsegment,Classified=SVM_LABEL_QOL) %>%
group_by(`Global Segment`) %>%
summarise(n=n()) %>%
select(`Global Segment`,Count=n) %>%
ungroup()

}) #close reactive function
```

**Step 2) Convert and store the filtered dataset into a set of different variables (still within the same reactive function)**

```
totalqol_enr <- unlist(subset(kpidf_pg1_totalqol(), `Global Segment` == "ENR", select = Count))
totalqol_def <- unlist(subset(kpidf_pg1_totalqol(), `Global Segment` == "DEF", select = Count))
totalqol_snr <- unlist(subset(kpidf_pg1_totalqol(), `Global Segment` == "SNR", select = Count))
totalqol_jus <- unlist(subset(kpidf_pg1_totalqol(), `Global Segment` == "JUS", select = Count))
totalqol_gov <- unlist(subset(kpidf_pg1_totalqol(), `Global Segment` == "GOV", select = Count))
totalqol_hc <-  unlist(subset(kpidf_pg1_totalqol(), `Global Segment` == "HC", select = Count))
totalqol_spl<-  unlist(subset(kpidf_pg1_totalqol(), `Global Segment` == "SPL", select = Count))
```

**Step 3) Based on a `selectInput`, the app displays a `valueBox` with the correct value from the previous step**

```
output$KPItotalqol <-renderValueBox({
if(input$inp_pg1segment=="ENR")
{
  valueBox(
    value = totalqol_enr()
    ,"Total number of QoL tweets identified"
    ,icon = icon("twitter-square")
    ,color = "green")
}
else
  if(input$inp_pg1segment=="DEF")
  {
    valueBox(
      value = totalqol_def()
      ,"Total number of QoL tweets identified"
      ,icon = icon("twitter-square")
      ,color = "green")
  }
else
  if(input$inp_pg1segment=="SNR")
  {
    valueBox(
      value = totalqol_snr()
      ,"Total number of QoL tweets identified"
      ,icon = icon("twitter-square")
      ,color = "green")
  }
else
  if(input$inp_pg1segment=="JUS")
  {
    valueBox(
      value = totalqol_jus()
      ,"Total number of QoL tweets identified"
      ,icon = icon("twitter-square")
      ,color = "green")
  }
else
  if(input$inp_pg1segment=="GOV")
  {
    valueBox(
      value = totalqol_gov()
      ,"Total number of QoL tweets identified"
      ,icon = icon("twitter-square")
      ,color = "green")
  }
else
  if(input$inp_pg1segment=="HC")
  {
    valueBox(
      value = totalqol_hc()
      ,"Total number of QoL tweets identified"
      ,icon = icon("twitter-square")
      ,color = "green")
  }
else
{
  valueBox(
    value = totalqol_spl()
    ,"Total number of QoL tweets identified"
    ,icon = icon("twitter-square")
    ,color = "green")
}

})
```

However this is producing an error that says function `Could not find function totalqol_def`

Any ideas on how this can work will be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you calling ```kpidf_pg1_totalqol``` within itself?

Comment: I recommend you take a look at https://www.programiz.com/r-programming/if-else-statement for proper  `if else-if else` statements.

Comment: @amrrs I've edited it. But it still gives me an error (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those functions expressions have to be included in `reactive` either Individually or combined.

Individually,

Example:

```
totalqol_enr <- reactive({ 
unlist(subset(kpidf_pg1_totalqol(), `Global Segment` == "ENR", select = Count))
})
```

So you can call those functions `totalqol_enr()`

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I included them individually and they work. I understand what I was doing wrong. When you say include those functions expressions in combined, how would you do that?